# Defining a debugging macro in assembly (with gas?)

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

For debugging outside a debugger, I'll often add in basic print statements, for example something like:

```
    str: .string "Hello!\n"

    mov $1,     %rdi
    mov $str,   %rsi
    mov $7,     %rdx
    mov $1,     %eax
    syscall
```

Is there a way to create a macro where I can instead write it like:

```
print ($str, $7)
```

And it would automatically expand to:

```
mov $1,     %rdi
mov $1,     %eax
mov $str,   %rsi
mov $7,     %rdx
syscall
```

I've looked at the [`macro`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html) docs for gas but it seems like it's using a syntax that I'm not sure where it's defined (it seems like they are using for loops?). Would it be possible to do the above in asm? I suppose if not I could create a snippet in vim that would 'expand' to the above.

---

Thanks for the suggestion. The tested macro I used to print the above is:

```
.macro DEBUG str_addr, str_len
    mov $1,         %edi
    mov $\str_addr, %rsi
    mov $\str_len,  %edx
    mov $1,         %eax
    syscall
.endm

DEBUG str, 7
```

While the syntax is a bit odd, for 'normal instruction' (and not a loop or conditional, for example), the macro syntax is called as:

```
macro arg1, arg2
```

And defined as:

```
.macro <macro_name> <arg1>, <arg2>, ...

.endm
```

Variable names need to be escaped with `\`. So for example to reference `arg1` you have to do `\arg1`.

Comment: CPP macros are usually easier to use than GAS's native macros.  And if you want `()` around the args, you might need CPP-style macros.  I think calling a GAS macro uses syntax like an asm instruction, `macroname  arg, arg`.  You can see this if you google for `gas macro` and look at some examples that crop up in SO questions.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see. Are macros considered 'bad practice' in assembly, or are they used at all?

Comment: Asm macros do get use, they just don't use the syntax you asked for so I suggested CPP macros.  GAS macros are less convenient than NASM in some ways, at least if you want to repeat something a variable number of times, but this is simple enough.  A debugging-print macro can make sense if you're careful to remember what registers it clobbers.  (You might want to push/pop all registers used around the macro, including RCX and R11) Normally it works well to use a debugger to see where execution goes: unlike C, the machine does directly execute your instructions so debuggers are extremely useful.

Comment: Also, asm macros make it easy to bloat your code if you're not careful.  And you lose the opportunity for optimizing between things if you just naively use a bunch of macros.  (If you don't care about optimizing, there's not much point in writing in asm.)  Not a problem for debug-print macros, of course; they're only for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  You should be able to do something like this (I don't have gas handy, so it's untested):

```
.macro myprint s, len
    mov $1,     %rdi
    mov $\s,    %rsi
    mov $\len,  %rdx
    mov $1,     %eax
    syscall
.endm
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
 myprint str, 7
```

Comment: looks good, I tested it, the only thing is the arguments need to be escaped(prepended) with ``\``.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 - please let me know the syntax that worked for you, and I'll update my response accordingly :)

Comment: just added it into the question.

Comment: Yea, I can call it as `DEBUG $str, $7` and just remove the two immediate `$`'s from the macro. But as soon as I remove the ``\``, I get a assemble error: `(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `str_addr'`.

Comment: Fair enough - thank you.  I'll update my post, and delete my extraneous comments.

Comment: thanks, by the way I'm a super-beginner in assembly, so everything I say take with a grain of salt!